# The numbers $n$ such that every sum of consecutive positive numbers ending in $n$ is not prime or A138666?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, oeis

> ***Question:*** Let $A(n)$ be a finite square $n \times n$ matrix with entries $a_{ij}=1$ if $i+j$ is a prime number; otherwise equals to
>   $0$. I write $|A_n|$ to count the number of $1$'s in $A(n)$ and set
>   $$f_{n}=2|A_{n-1}|-|A_{n-2}|-|A_n|$$ Suppose that $f_n=0$ and $n$ is
>   **not** prime is it true that $n\in$ [A138666](https://oeis.org/A138666).

The sequence of integers, $|A_n|$, can be found [here](https://oeis.org/A292918). In general I have that $$f_n=-2,0 \text{ or } 2$$